# What is the best approach to represent a generalization case for a forum website

Tags: php, sql, pdo, orm, uml

I've modeled the following UML for the database of our website (uni project):
[image: UML diagram]

However, I can't seem to find how to convert to SQL the generalization case between Post, Story and Comment. My teacher suggested to use the same table, but I think that limits me if I want to add more features, like tags for stories. Right now I already have two extra relations: a post can have several child comments, and a story belongs to a specific channel.

Should I follow my teacher's suggestion? Or should I use 3 classes?

Answer (score 3):

Since your class hierarchy has only two subclasses that come with only 3 additional properties (`title`, `channel` and `post`), you should use the *Single Table Inheritance* approach. Even when you may add a few more properties/methods later on, this will be the best choice, since implementing your class hierarchy with multiple tables would imply a much greater effort/overhead.

You can read more about this choice in the section [Representing class hierarchies with SQL database tables](https://web-engineering.info/tech/JsFrontendApp/subtyping-tutorial.html#secInheritTbl) (of a tutoral on handling class hierarchies in a JavaScript front-end web app authored by me).

Comment: That was just in my stomach.So yes. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

As always it depends. Having a single table has the advantage of accessing related post info in a simple query and just looking at a flag inside the column telling what kind of object you're dealing with. Having separate tables is a more "academic" way of solving it since you (as you noticed) have object information separated.

I'd probably go with the single table approach in this case. But - YMMV - you can as well stick to your 3 table approach. There might come other opinions here. Just wait a few days to decide :-)